# Is it possible to select default contact picture service?

Tags: contacts, facebook

Here is my problem: I merged all my Google and Facebook contacts in my contact list. When a contact has both a picture on Google and on Facebook, the picture from Google will be displayed.
I don't know if this is the default behavior, or if this is because I merge the Facebook contact into the Google one (but I want to keep doing that, to prevent my contacts from changing their names).
Is it possible (built-in option, or external app), to change this behavior and display the Facebook picture instead?

I have a Motorola Razr running Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Contacts Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luz.contactdialer). That is the only dialer app that I found that offered Facebook support, seems reliable, and offers a ton of extra features and settings (that you'll actually use). I just started using it myself and it looks promising. *The user interface is fantastic and very user friendly*. I also just noticed that **it does allow you to choose which picture you want to display**. Hope this helps!

Note: You should consider opting for the full version too. It's only $2.90 and unlocks many features. Well worth in imho.