# How to change the way joined contacts are displayed

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have several accounts synchronized on my galaxy S3 (google, google+, skype, facebook, linkedin) and I grouped the same contacts from various accounts into one.

How can I modify the way this merged account is visible in my contacts list? As an example I have the same person as:

- in linkedin: John Doe + ugly picture
- in google: Johnny + nice picture
- in skype: The mad guy + no picture

When merging these contacts I usually end up with the combo "the mad guy" + ugly picture, or whatever combination. I obviously would like to have "John Doe" + nice picture.

Is there a way to select what element should come from which contact?

Fallback question: in case this is not possible: is there a way to enforce one of the contacts as the "master one" ? (I would choose google as I have the most control over that one)

Note: This question was [initially asked on Phandroid](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/712088-how-change-way-contacts-displayed.html) but it will hopefully apply to any Android device

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: Related question: [Is it possible to select default contact picture service?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19699/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open joined contact > menu button > mark as default > chose account, name, phone.

Thats all.